# Why can you select a calculation and get a result, but can't get a result when selecting a function that has the same calculation?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In plpgsql, I'm trying to test a calculation. To see a result in my sql editor, I can do the following:

```
select 3 * 5;
```

Then when I highlight the code in my editor and run the query, I get the result ?column? with a row with the value 15.

But if a create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN SELECT 3 * 5; END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

and then highlight and run the query:

```
SELECT do_something();
```

I get an error saying that the "query has no destination for result data".

I just want to be able to test blocks of code and see results even if it's not associated with a table. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: don't return void but your value?!

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is that the function is declared to return nothing `return void`. If you want to return an integer, you need to change that to `return int`.

Additionally in PL/pgSQL, you need to use `return` to return a value, not a SELECT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something() 
  RETURNS int 
AS $$
BEGIN 
  return 3 * 5; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Note that for a simple calculation like that a `language SQL` function is more efficient, as PL/pgSQL does have some overhead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something() 
  RETURNS int 
AS $$
  select 3 * 5; 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want to know why selecting a calculation returns a result, but executing the same thing in a function does not. Also, return void in a plpgsql is completely valid. There are many instances for using functions that don't return values.

Comment: @u84six: because your function is incorrect (`returns void` can never return anything), that's why it doesn't work. Calling it should actually result in an error ("select has not destination") or something like that.